# Why do I experience a voltage drop between logic gates when combining multiple gates (7408 and 7402)

Tags: voltage, digital-logic, ttl

I am trying to combine logic gates (using ICs instead of trying to piece them together using transistors or MOSFETs).  Below is the simplest example of what I am trying to accomplish, though ultimately I would like to be able to combine 10 or more logic gates together in series.  In short, the problem I have is anytime I have an output from one of my gates it shows the appropriate voltage, but immediately when I connect that output to an input of another successive gate the voltage on that gate is almost cut in half resulting in the input being somewhere between high and low.  I [looked at this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/72334/how-to-combine-multiple-transistor-logic-gates-without-gigantic-voltage-drop) and read it over a few times, but am not able to apply the answer to my problem especially if I want to create a network of logic gates rather than just combining a NOR and NOT to get an OR.  I also don't have a firm understanding of TTL, which is why I am using IC packages.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9jAwo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When I breadboard this out using +5V as high, I get something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC2RVj.png)</sup>

Again, when I leave the output of the 7408 open and look at the voltage it is 5V, but immediately when i connect that output to the input of the 7402, the voltage drops to 2.6V.

I have a feeling that I am missing something pretty basic here but have rebuilt circuits like this several different times with different gate combinations and see the same thing occur when I try to take a logic 1 output from one gate and feed it as a logic 1 to the input of another.

Am I using the ICs properly?  Can anyone tell me why the voltage is dropping between the gates?

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Thanks, markrages.  The answer is plain as day - i just didn't read the pinout closely enough.  I also realized that I pulled the 74LS02 out of my bag of 7432s and didn't put two and two together when asking the question.  I swapped the chip out for a real 7432 and the circuit did in fact work as pin 1 on the 7432 is an input.  Is it possible to remove this question all together?  I don't want it to show up as noise when others search for their issues.

Comment: It's useful enough to leave it.  You're not the first person to experience bus contention.

Answer (score 10):

You are connecting to the output of the '02, not the input:

[image]